# ASP.NET MVC3 cascading DropDownList is not working properly

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I'm using cascading dropdownlist. When I select make it post makeId to the server using webservice and returns models. Then I add models to dropdownlist

The problem is. If I inspect models dropdownlist in firefox using firebug tool, I'm able to see just added models, but when I click it opens empty.

I'm using jQuery Mobile and jQuery Selectbox.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Makes').change(function () {
            getModels();
        });
    });

 function getModels() {    
    var make = $('#Makes').val();           
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Services/CarService.asmx/Models",
        data: "{makeId: '" + make + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
            var models = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            $('#Models').attr('disabled', false).removeOption(/./);         
            for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
                var val = models[i];
                var text = models[i];
                $('#Models').addOption(val, text, false);    
                alert(models[i]);
            }
        }
    });
}


@Html.DropDownList("Makes", "Please select make")
<select id="Models"></select>

[WebMethod]
public List<string> Models(int makeId)
{
    var dataContext = new SearchModel();
    var models = from m in dataContext.GetAllModels()
                 where m.Id == makeId
                 select m.Model;
    return models.ToList();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
var ModelSel = document.getElementById('Models');
for (var i = 0; i < models.length; i++) {
     var val = models[i];
     var text = models[i];
     ModelSel.options[i]=new Option(val, text);    
}
```

Comment: ok try another approach to add options instead of `addOption`.ex `$('#Models').append('<option value="'+val+'">'+text+'</option>');` but I am not sure this will make differene but let's try

Comment: It's the same. I have found the issue is because I have reference to jQuery mobile. So cascading drop down lists working but without reference to jQuery mobile

Comment: But it's not a fix for me because I need to use jQuery mobile

Comment: opps so I think you have to use plain javascript try my new answer

Comment: sorry it is my mistyping fault it must be `options` not `option`

Comment: It was mistyping, but I have the same issue when I add reference to jquery mobile framework ..

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery mobile so I can not target your problem please read jquery mobile documents carefully it may help you   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for my problem

Refreshing a select

If you manipulate a select via JavaScript, you must call the refresh method on it to update the visual styling. Here is an example:

```
var myselect = $("select#foo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");
```